# How to save hierarchy object ?

Tags: android

Lets say i have 4 objects YearCollection, Year, Month, Day.

The YearCollection hold X object of Year
A Year hold an array of 12 month
A month hold array of X days (  28 < X < 31 )

Each of the object contain his own fields also.

Now, i want to give my application a persistent ability. 
And each of the object must be save - and the hierarchy tree must be also save.

What is the best way to do it on android ?
( beside to save it to a file using Serializable )

Comment: Serialization - What's wrong with that?

Comment: Use database? Store it in shared preferences? Parse it to JSON and save as a string? And yeah, what is wrong with serialization?

Comment: as far as i know - saving to file is using Serialization  - and i can't save to files. so, saving to DB .. but i don't know good enough DB on android

Comment: Well... Database is a file as well, you can do whatever you want but eventually everything which is persistent will be save in some kind of file.

Comment: if i save to a file - what is the recommended location to save it ?

Comment: Application private space: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the stuff to... (Drum roll) SQLite database!

You can follow the instructions on the official android website about SQLite databases. (But not the docs for `SQLiteDatabase`!) you create some classes and write some SQL queries. Hopefully you know how to write SQL!

If you don't or you think it is a waste of time to do all the stuff just to save some dates, use the one and only... (another drum roll) SugarORM!

SugarORM is really good. It is an Object Relational Mapping library. You just searched its name on Google and BOOM! You will see how easy it is!

I just can't resist to explains it here briefly. You basically make your YearCollection extend `SugarRecord<YearCollection>`. And you just save the object by calling... Yes you can even guess it, it's `save()`! You don't even need parameters! And you can get the object back by calling `listAll()` or `find`. It's soo straightforward.

When i first used it and it worked, I cannot believe my eyes! Try it out!